# Css flex макет header main footer

Tags: css, flexbox

У меня никак не выходит сверстать такой макет. Нужно, чтобы:

1. Шапка была всегда вверху
2. Main занимал максимум свободного пространства, а если что-то не помещается, то появлялся бы скролл
3. Footer должен быть внизу экрана и всегда быть виден. Это поле ввода текста, если что. Футера на странице может и не быть.
4. Это всё находится в контейнере height: screen

Я верстаю на флексах и всё время упираюсь в то, что flex-grow, shrink, как я понял, не работают с height: screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если нужно чтобы скролл был непосредственно на `Main` (там где контнет), то используйте `flex`. Для `wrapper/body` задайте высоты `100vh`, для шапки и подвала высоту, а для `main` используйте свободную ширину. Примерно так: https://codepen.io/jurij-kopot/pen/PoEdOzr
2. Если скролл нужен на всю страницу (чтобы он был и на шапке и на футере), но скролился только контент, можно попробовать прибить шапку и подвал, через `position: fixed`. Примерно так: https://codepen.io/jurij-kopot/pen/dyJqZpg

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы отправить код в code pen, например?) Просто у меня не работает jsfiddle